# Корректировка работы регулярного выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, есть регулярное выражение `"[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]* [a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]*"`, которое пропускает 2 слова. Как можно его изменить, чтобы пропускало неограниченное количество слов, должно пропускать слова без знаков и цифр разделённые пробелом и состоящие либо из букв латинского либо кириллического алфавита?

Comment: Посмотрите про символ \b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так

```
^(?:\b[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+\b\s*)+$
```

Проверить можно здесь [Java Regular Expression Tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output)

Это пропустит: ertyhj  dbdbgf  errgdtg

А это нет: ertyhj  dbd345bgf  errgdtg.

Так как  здесь есть слово с цифрой, или должно пропускать все, а это вырезать?

Comment: не работает, увы(

Comment: поправил ответ и указал где можно проверить

Comment: Каждое слово нужно проанализировать на соответствие формату, т.е. если хотя бы одно слово содержит цифру или знак, то выдаём ошибку. Вырезать ничего не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало)